# Looking for help editing this sql statement

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT c.COLORNAME, x.COLORANTNAME 
FROM Color c LEFT JOIN Formula f ON c.COLORCODE = f.COLORCODE 
LEFT JOIN Colorant x on x.COLORANTCODE = f.COLORANTCODE;
```

i want this code to return all of the colorant names for one color in one row but it adds a row for every colorant in the color. any suggestions?

```
+---------------+----------------+

| COLORNAME     | COLORANTNAME   |

+---------------+----------------+

| TangierIsland | Organic Yellow |

| TangierIsland | Black Oxide    |

| TangierIsland | Red Oxide      |

| BarnRed       | Organic Yellow |

| BarnRed       | Black Oxide    |

| BarnRed       | Red Oxide      |

| BarnRed       | Titanium White |

| BarnRed       | Magenta        |

| NavajoRed     | Brown Oxide    |

| NavajoRed     | Titanium White |

| NavajoRed     | Organic Red    |

| NavajoRed     | Medium Yellow  |

| DustyMauve    | Black Oxide    |

| DustyMauve    | Medium Yellow  |

| DustyMauve    | Magenta        |

| Silver        | Phalo Blue     |

| Silver        | Raw_Umber      |

| Silver        | Magenta        |

| JPastel       | Raw_Umber      |

| JPastel       | Medium Yellow  |

| JPastel       | Magenta        |

+---------------+----------------+
```

^this is the output generated by my sql statement but i want it to look like this:

```
TangierIsland | Organic Yellow, Black Oxide, Red Oxide

BarnRed | Organic Yellow, Black Oxide, Red Oxide, Titanium White, Magenta

NavajoRed | Brown Oxide, Titanium White, Organic red, Medium Yellow, Magenta
```

ect ect.

Comment: Can you please post some example data? This makes it easier to understand. Post some rows of your table, the output of that query and your desired output.

Comment: ok i added the output and what i need it to look like

Comment: I think you'll have to use PLSQL with a cursor on the SELECT x.COLORANTNAME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use GROUP_CONCAT( x.COLORANTNAME ) instead of x.COLORANTNAME:

```
SELECT c.COLORNAME, GROUP_CONCAT( x.COLORANTNAME ) 
FROM Color c LEFT JOIN Formula f ON c.COLORCODE = f.COLORCODE 
LEFT JOIN Colorant x on x.COLORANTCODE = f.COLORANTCODE;
```

which results:

```
+---------------+--------------------------------------+
| COLORNAME     | GROUP_CONCAT(x.COLORANTNAME)         |
+---------------+--------------------------------------+
| TangierIsland | Organic Yellow,Black Oxide,Red Oxide |
+---------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Also you can set different separator instead of comma:

```
GROUP_CONCAT( x.COLORANTNAME SEPARATOR '-' )
```

Comment: thanks im new to mysql and was not aware of that function my final code looks like this and works as intended:     select c.COLORNAME,GROUP_CONCAT(x.COLORANTNAME) as Colorants FROM Color c left join Formula f on c.COLORCODE = f.COLORCODE left join Colorant x on x.COLORANTCODE = f.COLORANTCODE group by c.COLORNAME;